# How to block access from all hosting services? (like gutenberg.org)

Tags: firewall, ip, blocking, csf

gutenberg.org blocks access to all hosting services as per
http://www.gutenberg.org/error403.php

How to achieve this? Is there a list of hosting ips? Also, would these be added to CSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's achieved with a blacklist.  They have a list of IP address blocks allocated to big hosting services, and redirest traffic coming from those IPs to the 403 page you included.  So that's how you'd do it, yes.  Of course, as with any blacklist, it's not comprehensive and the smaller or more obscure hosts tend to slip under the radar.

Comment: It has to be added that the Gutenberg project is using mechanisms to detect automated queries so addresses are added to the blacklist dynamically according to [this announcement](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:Information_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages): *"Any perceived use of automated tools to access the Project Gutenberg website will result in a temporary or permanent block of your IP address."*

Comment: Ok thx. Is there such a list of ips publicly available?

Comment: @giorgio79  Not that I know of.  If you want to compile one yourself, it wouldn't be too hard.  Start with the address blocks assigned to big hosts like Amazon, Azure, Rackspace and the like, and go on from there - look up smaller hosts and their IP blocks, and see if you can profile traffic with some scripts to differentiate between hosted and non-hosted traffic, and use that to continue building out your list.